How to restrict the type of an instance when the instance requires a "* -> *" type in Haskell?
I'm trying to design a type that holds some value and keeps track of all operations done upon it. It does this by storing them in string format (this is not for a project, just learning)
I tried to make it a Functor like this:
data WithLogs a = WithLogs {value :: a, logs :: [String]}
instance Functor WithLogs where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> WithLogs a -> WithLogs b
  fmap f WithLogs {value, logs} =
    let newValue = f value
        newLogs = logs ++ [show value ++ " -> " ++ show newValue]
    in WithLogs {value = newValue, logs = newLogs}

This gives me an error at the line "newLogs = logs ++ [show value ++ " -> " ++ show newValue]", saying "No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’". I then add the required contraints to make sure that both a and b can be shown
instance Functor WithLogs where
  fmap :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> WithLogs a -> WithLogs b
  fmap f WithLogs {value, logs} =
    let newValue = f value
        newLogs = logs ++ [show value ++ " -> " ++ show newValue]
    in WithLogs {value = newValue, logs = newLogs}

This then gives me the error "No instance for (Show a) arising from the check that an instance signature is more general than the type of the method (instantiated for this instance)"
I think okay, so I need to constrain the instance, leading to this code:
instance (Show a) => Functor WithLogs where
  fmap :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> WithLogs a -> WithLogs b
  fmap f WithLogs {value, logs} =
    let newValue = f value
        newLogs = logs ++ [show value ++ " -> " ++ show newValue]
    in WithLogs {value = newValue, logs = newLogs}

This hits me with two* errors, the first being that the (Show a) in the instance declaration cannot be deduced, and its right, how could it? I can't pass a to Functor (WithLogs a) because Functor expects a (Type -> Type), but I somehow need to constrain fmap so that I can use show on the contained value. I need a way to tell WithLogs that it can only take showable types to be an instance of Functor. Is there a way to do this?
*: in case it's any help, the other error is "Could not deduce (Show b) arising from the check that an instance signature is more general than the type of the method (instantiated for this instance)"

You can't do that. It's a somewhat well-known issue. The standard Functor instance demands that fmap works with any types a and b, even those without Show, so you can't provide an implementation that only works in a subset of cases.

There's a variant of the Functor class that allows one to require extra constraints, but it's not the standard one. It's not widely used in the ecosystem, though.

a and b aren't "part of" the instance you're defining. The instance is just for WithLogs. a and b are merely part of the interface you are required to implement in order to define a Functor instance; you have to implement that interface exactly as specified by the Functor class, with no additional restrictions. It wouldn't make sense, as the whole point of an abstract interface is that other people will call your code through the interface without knowing they're dealing with your case in particular, so they wouldn't know to obey the restrictions.

You can make a logging map-like operation just fine though (with Show constraints). What you want to do is reasonable, it just isn't fmap from Functor; make your own definition, or use a different Functor like the one chi suggested. It does mean you can't have existing code that works for any Functor (via the interface that you can't change) use your logging map implementation, but there's no way that could possibly work, as that code already exists and uses the generic Functor interface without the Show restrictions no matter what you declare here.
